# Java Project: properties file automatically changing during execution

Tags: java, netbeans, tortoisesvn

I've checkout my java project from svn, And i import it in netbeans. My project has some properties file.
I edited the properties file and clean & build my project. I check my build folder my changes are there.
But when i run the project, changes in properties file are automatically reverted in build folder. So i got old answer.
This is the problem i am facing. Please someone guide me to solve this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using Maven? Where is the properties file you have troubles with in your project tree? When you run the project, is it from Netbeans after your clean & build, or are you doing it from another context (command-line, etc.)? It's hard to tell what your issue is just from your current description.

Comment: Am not using maven. My properties file is in src package. I've tried it in both the netbeans and tomcat cmd both results are same, properties file values are changing.

Comment: You may want to put these precisions in your question. I do not think the "tortoisesvn" tag is relevant, since your problems seems to be completely unrelated to version control. However, the "netbeans" tag is *very* relevant, since knowledge of that tool is necessary to answer your question. I used to use Netbeans, but that was years ago so I cannot help you I am afraid...